# Achieve better compression ratio on 7zip compression

Tags: file-compression

I use an open source compression software named Peazip running on a Intel Core i5-8250U @1.6 GHz processor. However, I have tried compressing files to 7z many times but the compression ratio is hardly less than 98%. Is it because of the processor or something else? Anyone please let me know how do I get a better compression ratio and do recommend any other alternative software that can achieve it. I have tried various compression softwares (even the official one), but the result hardly varies. If it some other issue let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor won’t affect the compression ratio that can be achieved, although it will affect the speed of the process.
You did not specify what kind of files you are trying to compress, but the type of file makes a huge difference in the amount of compression that can be achieved. A plain text file or uncompressed image will typically have a high compression ratio. If you are trying to compress an already compressed format you will not have a good compression ratio. For example, many media files like MP3 and JPEG are already compressed. Therefore, you cannot get a much higher compression ratio if you try to compress such a file. Also some types of data do not compress as well as other types.

The short version is that trying to compress an already compressed file will never work well.

Comment: The files are videos in HEVC format. If these won't give a good compression ratio which would? How are self extracting 7z file with high compression ratio of less than 50% created. I need to manage the space in my ext HDD. So I am trying compressing the video files in mkv and mp4 format. How do I do so?

Comment: @Sibasish Mishra HEVC format is already compressed, you cannot make them much smaller no matter what format is used.

Comment: What @Bill W said will apply to nearly all video files and similarly compressed files such as MP3s.  They are already highly compressed.  The only way to get them smaller would be to re-encode them at a lower quality setting, which will degrade the visual quality of the video.

Comment: But I really want to know how to compress to 50%, just like the software files we download from internet but they are installed onto our computers in sizes taht are 2-4 times the size of the installer. How do are these aoftwares compressed? That's my question

Comment: @Sibasish Mishra An installer can be very small because the installer does not include all the files that will be installed, rather it will download the required files as part of the installation process.